# How to constraint random spawn points to a road?

Tags: unity, algorithm

I have a terrain and a road.

I would like for spawn points to randomly appear on the road, and not outside on the terrain.

How to assign the spawn points to only be between the road and in random positions on the road?

Comment: What road do you mean? How is your road specified in code?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a box and spawn object inside it. Or if your road is windy you can use multiple boxes or some other shape. Here is some code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/// <summary>
/// Spawns a prefab randomly throughout the volume of a Unity transform. Attach to a Unity cube to visually scale or rotate. For best results disable collider and renderer.
/// </summary>
public class SpawningArea : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject ObjectToSpawn;   
public float RateOfSpawn = 1;

private float nextSpawn = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {           

        if(Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + RateOfSpawn;

            // Random position within this transform
            Vector3 rndPosWithin;
            rndPosWithin = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f));
            rndPosWithin = transform.TransformPoint(rndPosWithin * .5f);
            Instantiate(ObjectToSpawn, rndPosWithin, transform.rotation);      
        }
    }
}
```